# Calculating the latency of nodes in a WiFi network

Tags: networking, wifi, latency

I do already have an answer but am wondering if there's a any better way. The problem is: I have a set of clients on a relatively slow WiFi network. Each client has a distance to the access point (AP), which determines how fast that client-to-AP link will run. Shorter links run faster than longer links.

My goal is to have each node calculate the length of its own link (and that of all nodes in the network). Nodes can talk to each other, but always via the AP, of course. Knowing the distances between nodes and the AP lets us optimize the network simply by moving the worst nodes closer to the access point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use round trip time as http://www.tkn.tu-berlin.de/fileadmin/fg112/Papers/hoene_paper2.pdf suggest.
2. Read Wi-Fi signal strength and use formulas to calculate it as [How to calculate distance from Wifi router using Signal Strength?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11217674/how-to-calculate-distance-from-wifi-router-using-signal-strength) suggest.