# OpenWRT - How to reduce the effective Transmission Power or Distance?

Tags: shell, unix, configuration, openwrt

Basically I need to reduce the `RSSI strength`. I want my access point to monitor traffic only for my office premises.

My futile attempts : 
I changed the wireless config `/etc/wireless/config`

```
config wifi-device 'radio0'
    option type 'mac80211'
    option channel '11'
    option macaddr '0xff:0xff:0xff:0xff:0xff:0xff'
    option hwmode '11ng'
    option htmode 'HT20'
    list ht_capab 'SHORT-GI-20'
    list ht_capab 'SHORT-GI-40'
    list ht_capab 'RX-STBC1'
    list ht_capab 'DSSS_CCK-40'
    #option txpower '10'
    #option distance '5'
    option country 'IN'
    option disabled '0'
```

The **airodump-ng** output. It shows me the same amount of requests before adding these options in the above configuration

**option txpower '10'**

**option distance '5'**

I also saw a [link](https://befinitiv.wordpress.com/2015/02/22/finding-the-right-wifi-dongle-and-patching-its-kernel-driver-and-firmware/) which says that these values do not change at the lower level, inspite of changing the configuration. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tx power does not reduce your receive sensitivity. It only affects the packages you send.
If you speak in a low voice you still hear everyone close to you speaking loudly.

There is probably a better solution, but you could calculate the distance to each transmitter and keep only packets of the one in your distance of interest.

Calculate distance:
[How to calculate distance from Wifi router using Signal Strength?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11217674/how-to-calculate-distance-from-wifi-router-using-signal-strength)