# Android Wifi Distance

Tags: android, wifi, wifimanager

How would I get the distance of a router using android wifi manager. I was also wondering how I would know what levels the scan results would be to show that the router is unreachable.

Related: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html

What I was thinking of using to get the distance if someone can confirm this would work that would be greatly appreciated or: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-space_path_loss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though there is no way measure actual distance (Like in units such as feet or meters), you can measure signal strength with levels. Here is how you do it:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    int Levels = 5;
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    int signalLevel = WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(wifiInfo.getRssi(), Levels);
```

This code here will measure the signal in 5 level increments (Where 1 is the worst and 5 is the best). To make this more accurate you can change `Levels` variable

To find the distance refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11217674/how-to-calculate-distance-from-wifi-router-using-signal-strength)

Hope this helps!

Comment: keep in mind that, since this is reporting signal strength and not distance, the strength will depend on whether something gets in between the 2 devices. For example, if you have both devices sitting on a table, but you get people in between on/off, the signal value will vary even if the 2 devices are not moving at all

Comment: True I didn't think about that