# How to find distance of mobile phone from wifi router it is connected?

Tags: networking, wifi, router

I need to findout the distance between Wifi routers and devices connected in that Wifi. The Wifi is an open wifi, so there can be n connection.

The distance have to be tracked in wifi router not the device. Is it possible to do the same? If so then how?

Can we write a program and set the custom router for the same, if so, how can we achieve it?

Thanks,
Nikhil

Comment: this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11217674/how-to-calculate-distance-from-wifi-router-using-signal-strength

Comment: Thanks, but can we code in router and get the distances realtime? If so the which router to be used. Please advise on the same as well.

Comment: Wow thanks for getting more clarity. Can you put the solution in the Answer so rest can also be benefited.  I would also try the same and ask you more questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the router is linux-based, you may for example develop a simple C application periodically fetching `iw dev <your_wlan_interface> station dump` command output. this command lists all devices currently connected to "your_wlan_interface" and contains signal strength information as well.
Converting signal strength to the distance is another task to solve and in my opinion it is quite clearly described in the link provided