# How to locate an access point using user coordinates and signal strength?

Tags: android, triangulation, access-point

[image: Example situation]

Hi everyone,

I'm working on a school project for an android app where I need to locate all Access Points I can find and mark them on the map.
The problem is:
being x, y the coordinates of my phone
being s the signal strength of a given AP

how do I estimate the approximated x1, y1 of the AP location to mark it on the map?

Any tips on how to get ahead of this issue is welcome, I can't figure out how to do this without 3 signal repeaters.

Thanks very much.

[image: An example of how the app should look]

This is an example scenario where A is me on the map and the marker show the position of AP I'm finding and of those I have already found previously.

Comment: not clear. do you want to calculate the distance between hostspot and user?

Comment: I supposed known the distance between the user and the hotspot, I need to know the x and y of the hotspot, given the distance from me.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you could use ping value to the routers to estimate the radius in which the router could be but I don't think it can be so easily done, because ping depends on different factors. Here's a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071539/finding-out-distance-between-router-and-receiver)

Comment: That's a good hint for calculating the distance, but given that I need to know the approximate values of the x,y coordinates of the hotspot. For instance I know I have an hotspot at 50m from me, I need to know where it is in order to place a marker on the map.

Comment: You can move around an look for changes in ping to estimate the likely direction the signal is coming from. The further away you are from the router the lower the signal strength is

Comment: That's the trick I was thinking too, but wouldn't that be "too much effort" to ask to an average user? (I know I'm not constructive in my replies, my apologies for that I'm just discussing my thought)

Comment: I don't thing there's an other way. It could be introduced as "calibration" in the application to get an average estimate of the AP positions